# Convert to json object

Tags: java, json, spring

I've a POJO as below:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = @class)
public class TestClass {
    
    public final String var1;
    public final String var2;
    
}
```

Controller class

```
@Controller
public class Controller{
    
    //RequestBody passed : {"var1": "val1", "var2":"val2"}
    @PostMapping(value = "/test")
    public void testRequest(@RequstBody TestClass testClass){
        Map payload = new HashMap();
        //I think due to spring Config, testClass gets converted from json I pass to this format but in payload, I've to pass json.
        payload.put("classObject", testClass);
        payload.put("userId", "test");
        
        ResponseEntity<String> apiResponse = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, payload, String.class);
        
    }
}
```

Spring config file:

```
spring.jackson.mapper.USE_BASE_TYPE_AS_DEFAULT_IMPL: true
```

I've added this config, so rest api caller doesn't has to pass @class key in json.

I think due to spring Config, testClass gets converted from json I pass to this format.

```
TestClass{ var1:val1, var2:val2}
```

but I want it to following format, as I've to pass it in payload:

```
{"var1":"val1", "var2":"val2"}
```

Can you please suggest some pointers or code. Do I need to write a parser or any spring config would be helpful here?

Comment: Your setup looks correct. It should generate a payload akin to `{ "@class": "TestClass", "var1": "val1", "var2": "val2" }`. --- Why exactly do you have to decllare the type information anyway? This is normally to distinguish on the calling side between different implementation of an interface to deserialize with different imlementation classes.

Comment: @Turing85 Actually, in my project, POJOs are autogenerated and type information is added in all the POJOs, so I'll have to figure out another way i.e. without removing the type information as this POJO could have multiple usages in future. And I added mapper as I don't want UI to know the class name.